# MVC public folder htaccess is not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I recently moved my `index.php` (the file that handles routing) and CSS, JavaScript, and font assets to a `public/` folder. I only want items in this `public/` folder to be accessible for security purposes. I ran into this problem when I realized I could visit `mysite.com/composer.lock` and view the composer lock file with my old `.htaccess` and folder setup.

**Here is what I want**

If I visit `mysite.com/car/create`, I want it to actually point to `mysite.com/public/index.php?path=car/create`

If I link to an asset such as `mysite.com/css/style.css`, I want it to really point to `mysite.com/public/css/style.css`

**Here is my folder structure**

[image: MVC Folder Structure]

**Here is my `.htaccess` which is not working at all**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ public/index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

How can I fix this? It just generates empty pages and I can still directly visit files in the root directory, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your existing directives specifically avoid rewriting requests for existing files, so it would still enable you to visit files in the root directory. It will also rewrite static resources to `public/index.php?path=`, which will presumably fail.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Stop processing if already in the /public directory
RewriteRule ^public/ - [L]

# Static resources if they exist
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1 -f
RewriteRule (.+) public/$1 [L]

# Route all other requests
RewriteRule (.*) public/index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```