# PHP MVC .htaccess redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to write an MVC application in PHP and have the following file structure:

```
<pre>
/
|-- application
|   |
|   ...
|
|-- public
|   |-- css
|   |   |-- screen.css
|   |   `-- print.css
|   |-- scripts
|   |   `-- wlan.sh
|   |-- bugfixes
|   |   `-- audiofix.sh
|   `-- index.php
`-- .htaccess
</pre>
```

This is my [.htaccess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess) file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php [L]
```

What works:

- Redirect a virtual URI like '/something' to '/public/index.php' without changing the URI
- Redirect a file URI like '/css/screen.css' to '/public/css/screen.css' without changing the URI

What does not work:

- Redirect a directory URI like '/scripts' to '/public/index.php' instead of '/public/scripts'

I have tried everything. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Stop processing if already in the /public directory
RewriteRule ^public/ - [L]

# Static resources if they exist
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1 -f
RewriteRule (.+) public/$1 [L]

# Route all other requests
RewriteRule (.*) public/index.php [L]
```

Thanks to: *[MVC public folder htaccess is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41516541/mvc-public-folder-htaccess-is-not-working/41516968#41516968)*